# Getting highest even number out of an array

Tags: php

I need to get the greatest even number out of this array with a for-loop. I know how to get the highest number from the loop, but it's not even.

This is the code I have so far:

```
<?php
// array aangemaakt
$aReeks = array(23, 245, 1, 2, 12, -10, 46, 6, 66, 9999, -55, 348, 56, 6, 66, 983); 
$resultaat = 0;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($aReeks); $i++) {
    if ($resultaat < $aReeks[$i])
          $resultaat = $aReeks[$i];
}

echo $resultaat;

?>
```

Comment: Filter out the odd values, and then use max(): `$maxValue = max(array_filter($aReeks, function ($value) { return $value % 2 == 0; }));`

Comment: Or (for the benefit of future generations) using the possible new PHP 7.1 syntax: `$maxValue = array_filter($aReeks, function ($value) { return $value % 2 == 0; }) |> max($$);`

Answer (score 8):

```
if($resultaat < $aReeks[$i] && $aReeks[$i] % 2 == 0)
```

modulo of division by two is zero -> even number

Answer (score 2):

To find the **highest** **odd** number inside an `array`, you can use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) and [max](http://php.net/manual/en/function.max.php).

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983); 
echo(max(array_filter($aReeks, function($var){return(!($var & 1));})));
//348
```

---

If you just need to find if a number is **even** or **odd**, you can use:

```
//if Even Number
$number = "222";
if(!($number & 1)){...}

//if Odd Number
$number = "221";
if($number & 1){...}
```