# Getting average of all even numbers in array with for/while loop?

Tags: php

I have a array and i need to get the average of all the **EVEN** numbers in the array i already have tried this but it still doesn't work.

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983); 
for ($q = 0; $q < count($aReeks); $q++)
      {
          { 
            if ($aReeks[$q] % 2 == 0)
            $totaaleven = array_sum($aReeks[$q]) / count($aReeks[$q]);
          }
      }
echo $totaaleven
```

Comment: What's with the weird inner block? also, you need a `;` after `echo $totaleven`

Comment: Can't you figure it out from the answers given to all your previous questions this afternoon? Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37212309/getting-total-value-of-an-array-with-condition and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37210893/getting-highest-even-number-out-of-an-array

Comment: `$totaaleven = array_sum($even = array_filter($aReeks,function($v) {return $v%2==0;}))/count($even);` No (explicit) looping required...

Comment: I have to do it with a loop

Comment: I hope that your teacher appreciates that we're beginning to get fed up with you and the number of your fellow students who have been asking exactly the same questions all afternoon; especially as every question is just a minor variation on the others.... the max value, the average, the sum, etc

Answer (score 3):

I think this should work for you

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983); 

$evenSum = 0;
$evenCount = 0;

foreach($aReeks as $number) {
    if($number % 2 == 0) {
        $evenSum = $evenSum + $number;
        $evenCount++;
    }
}

$average = $evenSum / $evenCount;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can filter your array using [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for even number, and simply divide sum with count, see below:

```
$aReeks = array(23,245,1,2,12,-10,46,6,66,9999,-55,348,56,6,66,983); 
$evenNos = array_filter($aReeks, function($value) {
    return !($value%2);
});
echo array_sum($evenNos)/count($evenNos);
```